# Why does pygame need time.sleep in to play sound before exiting?

Tags: python, time, pygame

I am just playing around with Python playing MP3 files and bumped into `pygame`

I got it to play the music but somehow I need to add `time.sleep(SECONDS)` in order for the music to play or else it'll just exist right away when I run in terminal

Is there a reason for this or I am not doing it right?

```
import pygame, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, 16, 2, 4096)
pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("path/to/mp3/file")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
time.sleep(32)
```

I am not trying to create a game or anything, as I mentioned I am just playing around with Python

Comment: Well, if you don't `time.sleep()` it will exit right away... that's why you need the `time.sleep()`.

Comment: @kindall alright, because I was also reading documentation saying it'll play and also can pass integer for loops so I am kinda confused.  so if I want to play the whole file I need to find a way to get length of the music? :|

Comment: @Tsuna You should probably have it playing on a separate thread or have some other logic. You could just put `input()` to block until the user gives input. It's likely meant to be started, then the program enters the game logic and there isn't a worry of the program coming to an end.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy got it, guess I am not thinking at the gaming perspective that's why I get @_@ myself as I was just trying to find a library to play music with python.  Tried a few other simple lib but did not work and this does so got myself confused.  Thanks a lot for this explanation

Comment: @Carcigenicate thanks for this suggestion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To speak to the "why" -- `pygame.mixer.music` isn't really designed to be a foreground process: the idea is that this is background music to play while something else runs. If the user says they want to exit a game, they'll usually be annoyed if that game keeps running until the current background-music track is finished.

---

If you want to block until the music is finished, one inefficient-but-easy way to do that is with a loop that checks for completion:

```
while pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
  time.sleep(0.1)
```